# Set current thread dateTime format different than CurrentCulture setting

Tags: .net, desktop-application

I have similar function, where I can set culture in my application:

```
public void SetThreadCulture(CultureInfo culture, CultureInfo uiCulture)
{
     var t = Thread.CurrentThread;
     t.CurrentCulture = culture;
     t.CurrentUICulture = uiCulture;
}
```

Thanks for that I can then set correct translations for my app. But because of that all date formats are changed to chosen culture and I don't want that, I want to keep system settings.

Is there any way I can set CurrentCulture for any language I choose, but keep dateTime format according to my Windows setting? For instance I will set en-US in my app, but keep those formats I see here:
[System Region setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDEyi.png)

Comment: DateTime has no format, it's a struct that stores ticks as a `long` internally. Formats apply **only** when you parse strings into types, or generate a string from a type with `ToString()` or `String.Format`. Instead of setting the thread's culture, pass the culture to the `Parse`, `Format` or `ToString()` method you use

Comment: `CurrentCulture` controls how strings are parsed or formatted. `CurrentUICulture` controls which language is used to display the UI, which resources to load. If you want to change the UI language only, change `UICulture`, not `Culture`

Comment: If you use eg a [DatePicker control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker?view=netcore-3.1), you can get and set the selected and display dates through the appropriate properties, SelectedDate, DisplayDate. The culture *doesn't* affect that value. What it affects though, is how that date is displayed as text on the control.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that, but this is big app, there are thousands of places where I am displaying dateTimes, there is no way I am able to set format in every control and in every ToString() method